# how to display custom attribute on product view page in magento 1.9?

Tags: magento, attributes

I created one attribute "gmdn" on Magento and put it in attribute set default. But after I gave a value to this attribute, it is displayed in the additional information tab. But I want to display it below the name of product in the view page.

Comment: Where's the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, Your attribute code is **gmdn**, You need to do the following things at **/app/design/frontend/[your package]/[your theme]/template/catalog/product/view.phtml:**

```
1) <?php
    $gmdn = $this->htmlEscape($_product->getData('gmdn'));    
    echo $gmdn;    
?>
```

**Or**

```
2) echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getData('gmdn'));
```

These two are same. But representing way is diferent.

Answer (score 1):

For this you have to make changes in file

> app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/template/catalog/product/view.phtml

and add below code after product name division

```
<?php echo $_product->getGmdn() ?>
```

Comment: its not working . i have add                                                                 
    public function getGmdn()
    {
        return $this->_getData('gmdn');
    } in model and                                                                                                <?php echo $_product->getGmdn() ?> this line in view page .

Comment: you don't have to add any function, just add above code in your view.phtml file